# Client Side Validations Gem - is uniqueness validation is still working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, unique, client-side

I am using [client side validations](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations) gem and in the official documentation is recommended to turn off uniqueness validation due to security reasons:

> By default a uniqueness middleware is added. This can be a potential
> security issue.

So, following the recommendation I uncomment the following line

> ClientSideValidations::Config.disabled_validators = [:uniqueness]

in the  config/initializers/client_side_validations.rb file.

Anyway, when I am typing some text in fields that needs to be unique the following request is send by client side validations scripts which I believe is checking if the type in text is unique:

[image]

When I type some name  that is already taken, the request status is still not found, so I believe the validation is turn off, but why this request keeps going on and is there anyway to stop them?

I know the client user probably will not know what is going on at all, but I just found it unappropriate to send a request on each field text change.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well you disabled uniqueness remote validation but the app keeps sending the request, right?

If that's the problem, try restarting rails server.

Comment: I have done this two months ago. From then, a lot of restarts are done, but nothing changes.